# PyQt5 control windows

Tags: windows, pyqt5, controls

[image]

In the above imange the background window is the main window of the screen. Then follows one Form that opens from the menu of the Main Window
and at the top you can see a QMessageBox like this:

```
box = QMessageBox()
            box.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
            box.setWindowTitle('Αποθήκευση αλλαγών')
            box.setText('Θέλετε να αποθηκεύσετε τις αλλαγές σας;')
            box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes|QMessageBox.No|QMessageBox.Cancel)
            buttonY = box.button(QMessageBox.Yes)
            buttonY.setText('Ναι')
            buttonN = box.button(QMessageBox.No)
            buttonN.setText('Οχι')
            buttonC = box.button(QMessageBox.Cancel)
            buttonC.setText('Ακύρωση')
            box.exec_()
            if box.clickedButton() == buttonY:
                self.save_and_close(True)
                self.main_self.manage_microphone_window_is_open = False
                event.accept()
            elif box.clickedButton() == buttonN:
                self.main_self.manage_microphone_window_is_open = False
                event.accept()
            elif box.clickedButton() == buttonC:
                event.ignore()
```

I want in the bottom the Windows (bottom bottom there that start menu of windows and clock are) to show only one program.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd start by setting a parent for the message box.

Comment: Correct: 1/2 !!!

Comment: Then i will try to change Form to Dialog and set also the parrent.

Comment: 2/2 that was!! thanks musicmante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of musicmante i did the following:

1. I change Form Window to QDialog and set MainWindow as parent
2. I set a parent to box: `box = QMessageBox(dlg)`

Note than in step 1 when you copy paste the QWidgets from Form to new Dialog (in QtDesigner), you may change the title of window the icon of window the style of the window and perhaps any other window settings.